# Javascript - convert string to associative array and summarize by value

Tags: javascript, object, hashmap, associative-array, summarize

This is the first time I am working with javascript. I have the following string:

```
document.write(str)
[{"company":1,"number_employees":5},
{"company":4,"number_employees":25},
{"company":5,"number_employees":5},
{"company":2,"number_employees":5},
{"company":4,"number_employees":25}]
```

I need to convert this string such that I summarize them according to the number_employees as follows:

```
Three companies have number_employees=5 and two companies have number_employees=25
```

I am currently struggling to convert the string into javascript object. Once I have the asscoiative array, I can convert it into map and count the `number_employees`.

```
s_obj = eval('({' + messageBody + '})');
var result = s_obj.reduce(function(map, obj) {
    map[obj.key] = obj.val;
    return map;
}, {});
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
VM181:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
at onMessage ((index):41)
at WebSocket.<anonymous> (stomp.min.js:8)
```

Any help/hint/guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: First, use ``JSON.parse``, not ``eval``

Comment: `var s_obj = JSON.parse(messageBody);`

Comment: That is not a string.  Nor is it valid JavaScript.  Except for the `document.write(str)` piece and the lack of surrounding quotes it looks like JSON.  (In which case, you would do `JSON.parse('[{"company":1,...}])`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a couple of assumptions about your data, you might try something like this:

First, convert the JSON string into an Object using the JSON Object, then as you were attempting use `Array.prototype.reduce` to summarize - (you have the arguments reversed)

```js
var summary = {};
var messageBody = '[{"company":1,"number_employees":5},{"company":4,"number_employees":25},{"company":5,"number_employees":5},{"company":2,"number_employees":5},{"company":4,"number_employees":25}]';

JSON.parse(messageBody).reduce( (acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.number_employees] = (acc[cur.number_employees] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
}, summary);
for(entry of Object.keys(summary)) {
    if (summary.hasOwnProperty(entry)) {
        console.log(`There are ${summary[entry]} companies with ${entry} employees`);
    }
}
```